# Bluetooth not working on Dell laptop

Tags: hardware, bluetooth, manjaro

I'm using a Dell Inspiron N5030 laptop and want to connect my Bluetooth speakers (Ultimate Ears). Here some outputs:

```
$ uname -a

Linux sandy-pc 4.19.8-2-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Dec 8 14:45:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

+

```
$ rfkill list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

+

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-12-20 01:21:24 +01; 46min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 2060 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4670)
   Memory: 1.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─2060 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dez 20 01:21:24 sandy-pc systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Dez 20 01:21:24 sandy-pc bluetoothd[2060]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Dez 20 01:21:24 sandy-pc systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Dez 20 01:21:24 sandy-pc bluetoothd[2060]: Starting SDP server
Dez 20 01:21:24 sandy-pc bluetoothd[2060]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized

$ bluetoothctl

Agent registered
```

+

```
[bluetooth]# power on

No default controller available
```

+

```
$ dmesg | grep -i 'firmware\|blue'

[    0.534496] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.680030] acpi PNP0A03:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    0.769546] pci 0000:09:00.0: [Firmware Bug]: disabling VPD access (can't determine size of non-standard VPD format)
[   16.996999] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[ 1338.119780] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 1338.121301] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 1338.121308] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 1338.121312] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 1338.121328] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 1348.722030] audit: type=1130 audit(1545265284.923:73): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=bluetooth comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[ 1348.775361] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 1348.775363] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 1348.775370] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

+

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Wistron NeWeb Corp. DNXA-95 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [185f:30af]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

+

```
$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6482 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

[image]

One thing I've noticed is that the bluetooth service is disabled after every reboot. I have to run `sudo modprobe btusb` and `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth` every time. Is there a way to start it automatically?

Another thing: My BIOS version is A02, but from 09/13/2010. There is one from 2011. Could this be a problem?

With Linux Mint:

```
mint@mint:~$ hcitool dev
Devices:
```

Comment: 19.1 was released yesterday I see, that's Ok, Cinnamon preferably.

Comment: I'm going to do it tonight and let you know. Thanks so far!

Comment: No problem, you're welcome! See you later.

Comment: What's the output of "hcitool dev" ???

Comment: I've tried it now with Linux Mint, still the same outputs. There is no real output of `hcitool dev` (see above).

Comment: Thrash, I'm facing the same issue in my Asus laptop. I suspect of the bluetooth chip being hardware disabled, though it doesn't appear when doing `rfkill list`. If I have more info, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a dell xps 9370, and I could solve it with this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-oem-osp1
```

Which installed the following kernel:

Linux xps 5.0.0-1050-oem-osp1 #55-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 24 11:08:25 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2423019&p=13890776#post13890776)